# Is it possible to pull data from Heroku Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, flask, heroku, telegram-bot, pull-request

Currently I am working on a telegram bot using Heroku and Flask to deploy it. I wanted to store some data into a database then I came across Heroku PostgreSQL. I managed to store data into it but I am having trouble retrieving these data from Heroku PostgreSQL. I have research quite a bit but couldn't find much information about the process on pulling the data. Can someone enlighten me or suggest what are the steps to retrieve/pull these data from Heroku PostgreSQL with Flask?

The Telegram Bot is basically a random food generator. I have stored a list of food into the data and wanted to pull these data and random generator whenever user trigger the bot/action.

[Screenshot of the current heroku postgresql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J98S.png)

```
from os import environ
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS
from invokes import invoke_http

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = environ.get("DB_URL") or "postgres://database-url"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATION"] = false

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

CORS(app)

class Cusine(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "cusines"

    id = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key =True)
    cusine = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, id, cusine):
        self.id = id
        self.cusine = cusine

    def getId(self):
        return self.id

    def getCusine(self):
        return self.cusine  

    def json(self):
        return {"id": self.id,"cusine":self.cusine}

db.create_all()

@app.route("/getAllCusine")#
def getAllCusine():
    try:
        all_cusine = Cusine.query.all()
        cusines = []
        for row in all_cusine:
            cusines.append(row.cusine)

        return jsonify(
            {
               "code": 200, 
               "message": cusines
            }
        ),200
    except:
        return jsonify(
            {
               "code": 500, 
               "message": "error in getting all course" 
            }
        ),500
```

So, how can I pull the data from Heroku PostgreSQL using Flask?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried. The usual way is to demonstrate some examples / errors you have encountered, it will save the community from repeating the same and building on your work.

Comment: Actually I haven't really tried it yet because I not sure what is the process for Heroku PostgreSQL. Because it was my very first time using it and there is limited information about it.

Comment: "I managed to store data into it but I am having trouble retrieving these data"—how are you storing data? To retrieve data you'd just... run a `SELECT` query instead of an `INSERT`, for example.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for your recommendation. So sorry it's my first time posting on stackoverflow, hence might not be very familiar with the syntax here. But I have added the code directly already.

That said, the data that were currently stored inside the database was inserted manually using the heroku CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to extract the data from Heroku PostgreSQL.

I have changed the above code with the following.

```
import os
import psycopg2

DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']

def retrieveData():
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select * from table") #some sql statement
        conn.commit()
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()

     except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
         print(error)

     return result
```

It will return a list of tuple.

Remember to `pip install psycopg2-binary`

It is my very first time working with Heroku and PostgreSQL, which took me quite awhile to figure out. But thanks guy for teaching me how to properly use stackoverflow, appreciate it. Hopefully this can help someone out there (like me), who is new to PostgreSQL. Cheers :)